# To do a meeting or To make a meeting?

Tags: word-choice, verbs, do-vs-make

What is the correct way?

> a) To **do** a meeting
>
> b) To **make** a meeting

The context: when I want to make a business with someone from the internet I can tell him "I agree to this offer (business) but before, we have to do / make a meeting about the details."

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You might **do** a meeting if you're in Los Angeles

> P1: Let's **do** a meeting after lunch
>   P2: I don't **do** meetings

if you attended a meeting

> P1: Were you able to **make** that **meeting**?
>
> P2: No, I was running late and didn't **make** the **meeting**
>   P2: Yes, I **made** the **meeting**

meaning

> ...didn't **make** *it to* the **meeting**
>   I **made** *it to* the **meeting**

The phrase you are looking for is

> **have a meeting**
>
> We would like to **have** a meeting to discuss the details
>   We would like **to meet** to discuss the details

Both imply a **face-to-face** meeting.

Answer (score 9):

Might I suggest a few better alternatives :

> - To **conduct** a meeting.
> - To **have** a meeting.
> - To **hold** a meeting.
> - To **arrange** a meeting.
> - To **set up** a meeting.